# How to use .http files in Visual Studio 2022 with Windows Authentication?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2022 enables calling API endpoints from .http files. How can I configure a request or environment to use Windows Authentication?

Resources I have checked:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/http-files
- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/safely-use-secrets-in-http-requests-in-visual-studio-2022/